# C# smooth resize of the form (smooth resize efect)

Tags: c#, forms

First of all, beginner here, apologies in advance if my question has obvious answer, but until now, I didn't manage to figure it out.
So, I'm trying to make an Windows Form App. In this app I have two forms: the login form and main window form. To make it look more "fancy", after successfully logging in, the main window form must increase its size (same size as the login form) to something bigger. I managed to create the code I need, but the resize effect looks "laggy". Is there a way to make this smother? Or is there another way to make the resize of the form smoother?
PS. I have set the "FormBorderStyle" property to "None"
Bellow, my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SlindingPanel
{


public partial class MainWindow : Form
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Enables the timer
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }



    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Width >= 820 && this.Height >= 540) this.timer1.Enabled = false;

        else {
            // Resizes the form
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Width + 20, Height + 20);
            //Centers the form on the screen
            this.CenterToScreen();

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You are resizing 20 pixels at a time, have you tried with a shorter interval and smaller increment?

Comment: Looks the same. Only that the form increases it's size slower.

Comment: Are you seeing the controls redraw slowly? I'd imagine that this kind of resizing would be visually messy especially in a Windows forms app, can you not use another technology such as wpf?

Comment: I don't know wpf. I am new to C#. But, thanks for the idea. I'll do some research and see how can I change my app.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but I suggest using the "anchor" attribute of the UI controls.